# Firebase error (android) "There is no user record corresponding to this email id"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

`signInWithEmailAndPassword()` always returns "There is no user record corresponding to this email id" but I can see the email and password in firebase console, other sign in methods works fine, does anyone got an solution

my code:-

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                try {
                    CommonMethods.dismissDialog(getActivity());

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                        if (user == null) {
                            CommonMethods.customeAlertThinkly(getActivity(), "Oops!", "Please Register with Thinkly and then try to signIn.", "Ok", "nointernet");
                        }
                        if (user != null) {
                            if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    loginEmail(Email);
                                }
                            } else {
                                CommonMethods.customeAlertThinkly(getActivity(), "Oops!", "Your email or pen name is invalid. If you are a new user, please ensure you sign up with a valid email and verify the email before signing in.", "Ok", "nointernet");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        String errorCode = "";
                        if (((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()) != null) {
                            errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
                        }
                        if (errorCode == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        switch (errorCode) {

                            case "ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL":
                                CommonMethods.customeAlertThinkly(getActivity(), "Oops!", "The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.", "Ok", "nointernet");
                                break;

                            case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                                CommonMethods.customeAlertThinkly(getActivity(), "Oops!", "There is no user record corresponding to this email Id", "Ok", "nointernet");
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please add the code that you using.

Comment: Alex please check my code above.